# Anisotropic shader not working with new file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

so I tried following this (somewhat dated) [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4MTnpnahu0) to create an anisotropic material.

Unfortunately no matter what I do, the objects don't look anisotropic at all.

Here's my attempt at following the tutorial:

[image: Pots that should be anisotropic but aren't]

Even if I just open a plain new file, add a geometry, an HDR map as the background and set the Anisotropic shader, it doesnt work:

[image]

The only way I could see any anisotropy, was by downloading the example blender file from the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/anisotropic.html).

What could be missing from a plain new file, that the example file has? The cycles nodes look exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion, it looks like `new file` now (Blender 2.9) sets the new file render engine to Eevee and eevee doesn't seem to do anisotropic. 2h of life-time I'm never going to get back